# Media Query Strange Behaviour

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been tinkering around with the W3 editor looking into media queries. I am trying to understand why the background is always blue except on the lower width bound. From my understanding, at least one feature is always true therefore, after being inverted, it should always be yellow. However this is not the case and it is yellow only when the viewport is < 500.

Anyone know why this is?

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media not screen and (max-width: 600px) , (min-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @media Rule</h1>

<p>Resize the browser window. When the width of this document is 600 pixels or less, the background-color is "lightblue", otherwise it is "yellow".</p>

</body>
</html>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior seems to be correct.

The 'not screen' refers only to the first condition which it is part of, it does not affect the second condition (the min-width) so the max-width is ignored because we are on a screen and the min-width is obeyed.

Therefore, whenever the viewport is over or equal to 500px width, the background is blue. Whenever it is less than that it stays at the original color set above, yellow.

If you want both conditions in the media query to be ignored on a screen then you would need to put a not screen as part of the second condition too. because in a list of conditions they are independent of one another.

```
@media not screen and (max-width: 600px) , not screen (min-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, I thought 'not' applied to both